# While pasting the image taken from print screen onto word document, the document is getting corrupted

Tags: java

While pasting the image taken from print screen onto word document, the word document is getting corrupted.

```
    ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", file);
    InputStream pic = new FileInputStream("D:\\Word\\testimage.png");
    run.addPicture(pic, doc.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG,"testimage",Units.toEMU(350), Units.toEMU(350));
```

Error:
[image]

Comment: You code is confusing. You write an image to "jpg", read a file as "png" and add a picture as "jpg"

Comment: That is a typo.Keeping it uniform either i read jpg and add jpg or i read as png and add png, in both caes, the document is getting corrupt.